# Invalid expression term 'else'

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm a beginner with C# - I've only been learning for a few days. I'm trying to make a GW2 trading post calculator but I'm stuck. I'm trying to check if the length of a string is equal to 3 in case its a `-` (like `-21`), and the value of the int is negative. I seem to be having trouble seeing where I'm going wrong with this `else` statement.

```
        sellPrice = sellPrice * 0.85;
        profit = (int)sellPrice - buyPrice;

        String copperString;
        copperString = profit.ToString();
        int length = copperString.Length;

        if (length == 3 && profit < 0);
        {
            copperString = copperString.Substring(Math.Max(0, copperString.Length - 3));
            this.textBox3.Text = copperString;
        }
        else
        {
            copperString = copperString.Substring(Math.Max(0, copperString.Length - 2));
            this.textBox3.Text = copperString;
        }
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon from line `if (length == 3 && profit < 0);` and the code will compile.

Comment: @AlanMcgilvray tick the large check to the left of the answer you found most helpful to indicate it's accepted and the question is answered; and to reward the answerer.

Comment: still need to wait 2 mins, but dw i will:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` terminates an `if()` statement, and the `else` statement after it becomes a "dangling" else statement which is illegal.

Remove the `;` after 
  `if (length == 3 && profit < 0);` <~ this `;`

Answer (score 3):

Its because of `;`. it should be like

```
if (length == 3 && profit < 0)
{
   //TODO:
}
else
{
   //TODO:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `;` after `if --> if (length == 3 && profit < 0)`

Here is complete code:

```
 sellPrice = sellPrice * 0.85;
    profit = (int)sellPrice - buyPrice;

    String copperString;
    copperString = profit.ToString();
    int length = copperString.Length;

    if (length == 3 && profit < 0)
    {
        copperString = copperString.Substring(Math.Max(0, copperString.Length - 3));
        this.textBox3.Text = copperString;
    }
    else
    {
        copperString = copperString.Substring(Math.Max(0, copperString.Length - 2));
        this.textBox3.Text = copperString;
    }
```

Comment: What has this to do with the hell? However this is a classic typo.

Comment: Np. Remember, if debugger gives you very nonsensical report, or bigger ammount of code is underlined, control ";" and "()"s.